# VBA Access removing hard coded file paths

Tags: vba, ms-access

Program currently uses hard coded file paths and dbCurr with destinationptt as string. But would like to remove the hard coded file paths so program can run anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for are relative paths. You can get the Path of your Project by:

```
CurrentProject.Path
```

You can than add some string like

```
CurrentProject.Path & "\folder\file.txt"
```

You also can go up a layer by using `\..\`

```
CurrentProject.Path & "\..\file.txt"
```

For more information take a look at these posts:

[Access VBA - relative file references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389705/access-vba-relative-file-references)

[Relative instead of Absolute paths in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213584/relative-instead-of-absolute-paths-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Thanks. So we need to dim the path?

Comment: CurrentProject.Path is a built in function. So you can reference any folder or path relative to your application.